# Inactive navigation buttons

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to make a simple Master-Detail-FileViewer app. In the last FileViewer view I want to have a button, which has an option to make the file favourite (every file has an "id" string, which is appended to an Environment object). When you favour them, this object is shown at the master view for quick access for the user, linking to the FileViewer view. However, when the user taps and goes there, the button is inactive - you cannot tap it and it gets black from blue. If you want to remove them from favourites, you can't.
I'd really appreciate to tell me what is wrong and how to make the button active. No error is shown and the app doesn't crash. It just doesn't work.
Thanks in advance!

The files are either "judgement" and "secondary", both have id and title properties. The second picture is the problematic one.

[image: Normal condition]
[image: Problem]
[image: Master View]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@EnvironmentObject var favouriteList: FavouritesList

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            NavigationLink(destination: JudgementsView()) {
                Text("Judgements")
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: SecondaryView()) {
                Text("Secondary acts")
            }
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack {
                    if favouriteList.items.isEmpty {
                        Text("Nothing favoured")
                    } else {
                        ForEach(favouriteList.items, id: \.self) { id in
                            VStack {
                                HStack {
                                    ForEach(judgementsTAXraw.filter {
                                        $0.id == id
                                    }) { judgement in
                                        NavigationLink(destination: FileViewer(file: judgement.id)) {
                                            Text(judgement.title).padding()
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                                HStack {
                                    ForEach(secondaryTAXraw.filter {
                                        $0.id == id
                                    }) { secondary in
                                        NavigationLink(destination: FileViewer(file: secondary.id)) {
                                            Text(secondary.title).padding()
                                        }

                                    }
                                }

                            }


                        }
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    .navigationBarTitle(Text("Test"))
    }

}
}

struct JudgementsView: View {
var body: some View {
    List(judgementsTAXraw, id: \.id) { judgement in
        NavigationLink(destination: FileViewer(file: judgement.id)) {
            Text(judgement.title)
        }

    }
}
}

struct SecondaryView: View {
var body: some View {
    List(secondaryTAXraw, id: \.id) { secondary in
        NavigationLink(destination: FileViewer(file: secondary.id)) {
            Text(secondary.title)
        }

    }
}
}



struct FileViewer: View {
var file: String

@State private var showCopySheet = false

@EnvironmentObject var favouriteList: FavouritesList

var body: some View {
    Text(file)
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(""), displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
        Button(action: {
            self.showCopySheet = true
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "doc.on.doc").frame(minWidth: 40)
        }.actionSheet(isPresented: $showCopySheet) {
            ActionSheet(title: Text("What do you want to do?"), buttons: [
                .destructive(Text("favText"), action: {
                    if let index = self.favouriteList.items.firstIndex(of: self.file) {
                        self.favouriteList.items.remove(at: index)

                    } else {
                        self.favouriteList.items.append(self.file)
                    }
                }),
                .cancel()
            ])
            }
    )
}
}
```

Aaaand in a separate file is the object:

```
import Foundation

class FavouritesList: ObservableObject {
@Published var items = [String]() {
    didSet {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()

        if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(items) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "FavouredItems")
        }
    }
}

init() {
    if let items = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "FavouredItems") {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()

        if let decoded = try? decoder.decode([String].self, from: items) {
            self.items = decoded
            return
        }
    }

    self.items = []
}
}
```

Comment: Try to attach `.actionSheet` not to navigation bar Button, but to in-view Text. I recall met some complains against first case.